# I can not change XDebug settings like xdebug.max_nesting_level

Tags: php, phpunit, xdebug

i created a PHPunit test with a @dataProvider.

I created many test cases and got the following error:
"Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!"

I tried to solved the problem, by editing the php.ini as follows:

- comment out: "zend_extension="php_xdebug-2.2.7-5.6-vc11.dll"
- added: "xdebug.max_nesting_level=2500" after[XDebug]
- added: "max_nesting_level=2500"

But this do not solved my problem!
If i call phpinfo(); the value of "xdebug.max_nesting_level" remains at 100. I restarted the apache and my pc many times.

Have anybody a idea how to fix this or how the create a workaround for "Maximum function nesting level reached" ?

Comment: The `max_nesting_level` setting is there to protect against a potential infinite loop. Have you investigated the underlying issue to see which function is calling itself?

Comment: How do you launch the test suite: via command line or with an IDE? Are you sure you are changing the right files? Sometime the php.ini are different for shell and for apache. Try investigating launching the command `php -i | grep 'php.ini'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you two for your replay,
but i solved the problem!

It was a stupid mistake!

I have 2 more php.ini files in different folder °!° !?

- ...\WAMP_config\tmp\php.ini
- ... \WAMP_config\php.ini
- ... \WAMP\php-5.6.5\php.ini

If i edited all this files it work!

But now i have the error "Fatal error: Out of memory"
I can increase the value too, but i think i have too much tests.
Is ther a better solution to manage so much testcases?
Split it up in test suit?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has different php.ini files

Command Line app need to edit `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

With php5-fpm edit `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

ubuntu need to edit `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini` or `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini`

Answer (score 0):

try editing the /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini

Comment: Thank you,but i dont have this file!